# Change input value of text to -999 if it is NaN for all input text on page

Tags: jquery

I have want to change text value to -999 is its values is NaN. I do have code but, I want to do it for 50 inputbox and I don't want to write it 50 times. Please take a look at my code and give me your valuable suggestions.

```js
if($('input[name="tt1"]').val() === 'NaN') {
  $('input[name="tt1"]').val('-999');
};
if($('input[name="tt2"]').val() === 'NaN') {
  $('input[name="tt2"]').val('-999');
};
if($('input[name="tt3"]').val() === 'NaN') {
  $('input[name="tt3"]').val('-999');
};
if($('input[name="tt4"]').val() === 'NaN') {
  $('input[name="tt4"]').val('-999');
};

// and so on..
```

```html
<input name='tt1' value='NaN'><br>
<input name='tt2' value='NaN'><br>
<input name='tt3' value='NaN'><br>
<input name='tt4' value='NaN'><br>
and so on...

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) there is lots of options to chose from. If all your `input names` start with `tt` you can change your selector to the following

```js
$('input[name^="tt"]').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() === 'NaN') { // use $(this) here at that is one of each input elements
      $(this).val('-999'); 
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='tt1' value='NaN'><br>
<input name='tt2' value='NaN'><br>
<input name='tt3' value='NaN'><br>
<input name='tt4' value='NaN'><br>
```

Comment: You're just testing the first one, not all of them.

Comment: thanks @Barmar I wasn't sure if the test needs to be run on click of each item or so. Now it tests all of them, without needing to give them a class name

Answer (score 1):

Give them all the same class so you can select them together. Then use a function as the value, so it can check the current value and return a replacement.

```js
$("input.tt").val(function() {
  return this.value == "NaN" ? "-999" : this.value;
});
```

```html
<input name='tt1' value='NaN' class="tt"><br>
<input name='tt2' value='NaN' class="tt"><br>
<input name='tt3' value='NaN' class="tt"><br>
<input name='tt4' value='NaN' class="tt"><br>
and so on...

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```